# Does this log sequence converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{n}{n^2+5}\right)$$

I'm trying to solve this question by using the chain rule. But I'm stuck on simplifying the question. I got this after using the chain rule

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+5}{n}\cdot\frac{-n+5}{(n^2+5)^2}$$

by simplifying further my final answer is $-0/1$ which DNE, but the answer on my textbook is negative infinity and diverges.

Comment: Please type the formulas using MathJax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\frac{n}{n^2+5}$ tends to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ (divide the numerator and denominator by $n^2$ to see this). So, the natural log of it will $\to -\infty$ and it diverges.

Comment: Which means we don't need to use the chain rule to solve this type of question right?

Comment: No, you don’t. Although after differentiating, the limit of the fraction will still be $0$.

Answer (score 1):

As the natural log is a continuous function

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{n}{n^2+5}\right)=\ln\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^2+5}\right)$$

then since the degree of the denominator is greater than that of the numerator

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^2+5}= 0$$

hence

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{n}{n^2+5}\right)=\ln\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{n^2+5}\right)\to\lim_{x\to 0^+} \ln (x) = -\infty$$

which diverges.

Answer (score 0):

as $n \to \infty, \frac{n}{n^2 + 5} \to \frac{1}{n} \to 0,\;$ so the sequence approaches $\;ln 0\;$ which is $-\infty.$

Comment: You mean it converges to $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \log x = -\infty$.

Comment: @JairTaylor yes, my bad; i just corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that this is a composition. With $ln$ a continuous function on its domain $(0, \infty)$, and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{n^2 +5} = 0$, the limit $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ln(\frac{n}{n^2 + 5}) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} ln(x) = -\infty$.